# Google Colab csv file upload pathetically slow

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to upload a CSV file of ~1.5 GB to Google Colab from my local system folder. It took 5 minutes to complete 1% of the upload.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
import io
import numpy as np

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Is there a faster way to upload?

Comment: This is almost certainly a network issue, not something this code is causing (unless the client you are using is known to have some issue)

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I also got the same issue

I know one way maybe that one can help you

convert into a zip file

upload it on google drive

extract it using python

`!unzip -q file_path`